# Clearing the Error Message without page Reload

Tags: angularjs

I am working on registration page. In that my task is to verify whether the Mobile number exists or not, before form  submitting if it exits, means it should throw an error message like Mobile number exits. Its working fine but after displaying the error message, once I clear the field, the error message disappeared. But when I start typing a new mobile number It displays the error message again like "Mobile No Exits". Before checking only the message is displaying how can i avoid this. Please help me to find out the solutions.
Below is my code.

**Html code**, here I am using ng-blur for mobile number check function.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.MobileNo" placeholder="Mobile Number" 
    name="mobile" required ng-maxlength="10" maxlength="11" id="default1" 
    ng-blur="mobilenoCheckFun(user.MobileNo);">
   <span ng-show="!signupForm.mobile.$error.required  && show=='true'" 
   class="help-block">{{serverMessage1}}</span>
   </div>
```

**Controller Code**

```
$scope.mobilenoCheckFun=function(mobileno)
{
  $http.get("/ncrMobileCheck"+mobileno).success(function(result){
    console.log(result.length)
    if(result.length !=0)
    {

      $scope.show="true";
      $scope.serverMessage1="Mobile No Exits";
    }
    else
    {
       $scope.show="false";
       $scope.serverMessage1=" ";
    }
  })
}
```

**Edit - 1**

I'm editing my question because I also need help to validate the `email` field in the same `form.`

**Html Code for Email validation**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" ng-model="user.Email" placeholder="Email Id" name="email" required ng-change="emailIdCheck(user.Email)">
    <div ng-if="signupForm.email.$touched || signupSubmitted">
    <p ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.required" class="help-block">Email Id is Required</p>
```

**controller code**

```
$scope.emailIdCheck=function(emailid)
{
  $scope.serverMessage2="";
  $http.get("/ncrEmailIdCheck"+emailid).success(function(result19)
  {
    console.log(result19.length)
    if(result19.length !=0)
    {
      $scope.email="true";
      $scope.serverMessage2="Email Id Exits";
    }
    else
    {
       $scope.email="false";
      $scope.serverMessage2="";
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: First you should use only one attribute regarding max length, go for ng-maxlength.

Comment: ng-maxlength through the error message when it reaches the limit but it allows user to enter the character but maxlength restricts the entry after reaches certain limit...

Comment: It sounds fair. To fulfill both the purpose, you can use both.

Comment: yeah...i need both conditions to be satisfied.....

Comment: You can use ng-change and check length, set some boolean to true when length is correct and use ng-if directive on error message with this boolean which i mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ec395v9/).

You code seems a bit messy and carry something which is not required. Check your code below which I have modified and compare it with yours. You are working in real time scenario and using `http` call. In my case just to full the purpose I have taken the `array` example. It behaves exactly like yours. Below are the changes which I have done to your code.

- `ng-change` instead of `ng-blur`.
- Created one more method **checkIfNumberExists** to check whether the mobile number exists in `database` or not (In my case It's array). FYI, this logic should exist at your server.
- No need to use any extra variable `$scope.show` to display the error message, otherwise what's use of `form`'s `span`'s `ng-show` messages. Notice here, I have removed `required` from `ng-show`.
- In the method **mobilenoCheckFun**, use blank `string` when you don't want to show any message instead of a single space.

That's all. You are enough smart to understand the rest of code.

**HTML**

```
<form ng-app="myApp" name="signupForm" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.MobileNo" placeholder="Mobile Number" 
    name="mobile" required ng-maxlength="10" maxlength="11" id="default1" 
    ng-change="mobilenoCheckFun(user.MobileNo);">
   <span ng-show="signupForm.mobile.$error">{{serverMessage1}}</span>
   </div>
</form>
```

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){

    $scope.checkIfNumberExists = function(list, mobileno){
    if(list.length != null && list.indexOf(mobileno) > -1)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
  }

    $scope.mobilenoCheckFun=function(mobileno)
  {
        //define an array to check If 'mobileno' exists, in your case this check happens at server side. but the logic is same. This list is fetched from DB in your case
        var list = ["8123791223", "8123791225", "8123791221", "8123791203"];
      var result = $scope.checkIfNumberExists(list, mobileno);
      if(result)
        $scope.serverMessage1="Mobile Number Exits";
      else
         $scope.serverMessage1="";    
  }
});
```

Let us know If It was helpful.

**Edit-1**

As per your request in comment, I'm providing this update.

[Updated Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0xeawc7s/)

By default keep **serverMessage1** is blank and put a check on **mobileno** `length` to skip the web service call. When the **mobileno** `length` is 10 then only continue to make a web service call.

```
$scope.mobilenoCheckFun=function(mobileno)
  {
        //define an array to check If 'mobileno' exists, in your case this check happens at server side. but the logic is same. This list is fetched from DB in your case
      $scope.serverMessage1="";
      if(mobileno.length != 10) return;
        var list = ["8123791223", "8123791225", "8123791221", "8123791203"];
      var result = $scope.checkIfNumberExists(list, mobileno);
      if(result)
        $scope.serverMessage1="Mobile Number Exits";
      else
         $scope.serverMessage1="";    
  }
```

**Edit - 2**

You have modified your question and also want to validate `email` field of the `form`. Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/34h630cu/1/), which validates the `email` as well.

```js
  //this method has been modified and is made common method for both the checks (mobile and email)
  $scope.checkIfExists = function(list, input){
   if(list.length != null && list.indexOf(input) > -1)
     return true;
    else 
     return false;
  }
  
  $scope.validateEmail = function(email) 
  {
      var regEx = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
      return regEx.test(email);
  }
  
  $scope.emailIdCheck=function(emailid)
  {
   $scope.invalidEmailMsg = "";
    $scope.serverMessage2 = "";
    if(emailid.length == 0) return;
   //first check whether email id is valid or not
   var isEmailValid = $scope.validateEmail(emailid);//
    if(isEmailValid){
     //if valid then make a service call to check whether it exists in database or not, in my case i'm checking it in array
        var emailList = ["mike.gimpe@gmail.com", "ben.gimpe@gmail.com", "georges.erard@hotmail.com", "viktor.damian@yahoo.com"];
        var result = $scope.checkIfExists(emailList, emailid);
        if(result)
          $scope.serverMessage2="Email Id Exits";
        else
          $scope.serverMessage2="";   
    }else{
     //if it's not valid, do nothing, just show a message
     $scope.invalidEmailMsg = "Invalid Email Id";
      return;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.Email" placeholder="Email Id" name="email" required ng-change="emailIdCheck(user.Email);">
    <span>{{invalidEmailMsg}}</span>
    <span ng-show="signupForm.email.$error">{{serverMessage2}}</span>
    <span ng-show="signupForm.email.$error.required" class="help-block">Email Id is Required</span>
</div>
```

**Note -** Based on your need, you can change the `Regular Expression` to validate the `email` field. Here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) which provides lots of `Regular Expressions` to validate the `email`.

Comment: I'm glad, I could help you. Please accept the answer.

Comment: I have provided the answer as per you question but I am up here to help you. Let us know what problem you are still struggling?

Comment: Its working fine but the problem i am still facing is that.After checking for Existing mob number,If i enter new mobile number before checking only it will show error msg like Mobile No Exists..when i lost the focus means then the  function again compare the current no with my Existing data....

Comment: Are you still using 'ng-blur' or 'ng-focus'? You should use only 'ng-change'.

Comment: That's not a problem. You can still use 'ng-change'. You just need to put a check to skip a web service call. The event 'ng-change' is most preferred way to use in such scenarios. The 'ng-blur' will not work If user forgets to click outside of textbox. So using 'ng-blur' doesn't seem a feasible solution here. See my updated answer.

Comment: yeah you are right....i will fallow the same code....Thanks for your kind support...

Comment: If you are happy. Your little effort can make me happy too by accepting the answer.

Comment: Hai just know i implemented  the code with some changes  its working exactly as my requirement....thank you......

Comment: in the same way how i  can avoid the function call for email check..up to last character equal  to .com

Comment: Looks like you should also learn, how to work on StackOverflow. If an answer solves the question on StakOverflow. It should be accepted first to give him the credits for his/her effort in order to motivate the user. If you have any different question ask it separately. You are expecting more help and don't want to give value for the time which one have spent to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry..... You are Right i am knew to stack overflow...First i will accept your answer.....

Comment: It definitely motivated me. Provide the html code for email in your question.

Comment: Hai....just know i edited my question and added the Html and Controller code for Email Id validation please check it....

Comment: I have provided the Edit-2 in my answer. Check the live demo in Edit-2. Don't forget to up vote the answer for this effort if it solves your problem.